# Why Arrays HOC functions don't throw an exception when no parameter is available?

Tags: javascript

I have an array :

```
const values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And I'm trying to perform some HOC functions on it ( `forEach`,`every`..) for example :

```
values.forEach(() => {
  const bool = typeof value == "number";
  console.log(bool)
})
```

The code above works correct ( Without error ) even the result is `false` and the value should be `undefined` because I thought that I passed `value` ( Typo error ) like this :

```
values.forEach(value => {
      const bool = typeof value == "number";
      console.log(bool)
    })
```

My question why Javascript does not warn me or throw an error from this `method`?

Comment: What exactly is the "error"? Nothing in your code would produce an exception or anything like that.

Comment: Also what does "HOC" mean?

Comment: @Pointy Higher Order...Component?

Comment: `typeof someUndefinedVariable` will never result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of the `forEach` method. that's how `typeof` works, it evaluates the data type of the variable, in case it's not defined, it'll return "undefined".

```
typeof value === "number"

typeof value //"undefined"

"undefined" === "number" //false
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

`typeof` will always return a string, so normally we do

```
  typeof A === 'number'
```

We normally use `===` as well. But this shouldn't give an error even it's not a match.